# Relationship between objects and whether they appear in the fields and relationships

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, relationships

Say I have an object A, and object B. A is related to B via One-To-Many.

In the object manager for A, I don't see B listed. However, in the object manager for B, I see A Master-Detail(A).

Is the expected behavior? Because I'm having issues doing a nested SOQL query. I'm just checking if the basics are correct before I move on to more debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very much expected behavior, you will see the field (reference) of parent on the child side. While, in the UI, you will see the related list of child records on the parent's record detail page. For more details on salesforce relationships review this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/relationships_among_objects.htm).

For Soql

If you are writing a soql on parent and fetching child record, then

`SELECT id, name, (SELECT name FROM objB) FROM objA`

will return corresponding child records against each parent record.

If writing soql on child obj and fetching parent, then

`SELECT id, name, objA_Id, objA_Id.name FROM objB`